# How to address the topic of seeking professional help with a narcissist?

Tags: narcissists

I have a friend where I have strong indications that she has (Narcissistic personality disorder) NPD. For the answer please assume that she has NPD, is unaware about it, that I am able to shield myself sufficiently that moderate exposure will not affect me strongly, and that I have manipulative skills sufficient to manipulate her, albeit I prefer not to do that.

She currently is ok, set aside from toxic behavior but the last time she had a personal crisis (end of a long relationship and a following toxic relationship) she was highly erratic and inconsistent in reasoning and exhibited clear errors of judgement regarding her personal mental health and relationships far outside of the normal range expected for her background (back then I did not connect the dots enough to believe she had NPD).

I may like her to be better prepared for the next crisis, may it come or not. So I want to tell her that she should seek professional help. My question is: how can I address this topic in a way suitable for this personality disorder?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or have there been things you've thought of trying that you dismissed as probably not a solution (why?)? If you can include any details like that, answers will probably end up less like 'just throw mud at a wall to see what sticks' or suggesting directions that may not be an option for you.

Comment: I left that open intentionally. I have some ideas how i would tackle it, but it's the first time that I am friends who has NPD with enough symptoms that I would suggest to seek help. If I can not help her to see this trough then I would end the friendship, since there would be nothing in it for her either. The basic options are to do this as part of some advice given as a farewell or try to continue the friendship.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: and no, I did not try anything yet, i put the friendship on hold for some time because her behavior became to toxic.

Answer (score 3):

Getting someone else to seek help they don't think they need is a challenge, indeed. I've tried a few times and occasionally succeeded. My tips:

- do not tell them what you think they have. That just opens a line of arguing about whether they have it or not or whether you're qualified to have an opinion or not.
- do not start by telling them what you want them to do (see a therapist.) They have no reason to agree, so they will likely disagree immediately.

If that's what you don't do, what should you do?

- remind them of a bad time they went through, using gentle language like "things really went sideways" or "you had a very hard time" and get them to agree they didn't enjoy that at all.
- tell them, with the disclaimer that it's easier for you to see this from a slight remove, that you think you see some patterns that might be leading there again. Express concern and a wish to save them from that "hard time". Not yourself, them. You are offering a gift.
- If they seem like they are engaging with this line of thought, suggestions of "seeing someone" might be taken well at this point. Probably with a disclaimer of "the right kind of someone, of course, someone who can help you work out how to handle things" in case there is a quick rebuttal like "I don't want to go on any meds" or "I don't need my head read" and so on.
- If you have personal experience (your own or someone close to you) with the sort of someone you intend to recommend, now is a good time to offer it. "When my sister did CBT nobody was interested in getting her to remember her childhood or blame our parents or anything, they provided coping techniques for when things were hard and she says it was really useful." If you don't then you can perhaps offer a slightly weaker "I read an article that said..." explanation.

If your goal is truly to prevent the kind of crisis you saw before, this may work for you. If your goal is to get your friend to admit they are a narcissist, so much so that it's a personality disorder, and agree to try to be cured of it, I don't predict success. But then again, I don't think that's a good goal for you to have, so my advice is more to what you asked in your question, how to help her be prepared.

I think the specific tips I've outlined here are pretty good for anyone facing a possible health issue ("mom, you know your knee is keeping you from doing a lot of things lately") but for a narcissist specifically, you will notice it avoids any suggestion that your friend mishandled the previous crisis, should know by now another is on the way, or is mishandling their current situation. It leaves little to argue about, though of course your friend may just brush you off and ignore your suggestions. That does happen sometimes.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - you cannot cite when its personal experience or input from a therapist. Its too personal.  Kate Gregory didnt cite anything either. I gave tips based on personal experience just like she did. I'll just leave this site since you seem to be using double-standards. @ kategregory I am not criticising your answer btw - its fine